# After south migration failed on sqlite, I switched to MYSQL

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

So I am a newbie to Django and I had added a field to a model.py and that created issues in Django.

I learned I needed a migration tool, and used south. Turns out south has issues with sqlite. So I configured Django settings for MYSQL. I can add data to the DB (MYSQL)

I deleted the db.sqlite3 file , but it comes back after ever syncdb.

When I run syncdb it says:

```
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > south

Not synced (use migrations):
- accounts
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

So my questions are:
1. Changing to MYSQL did not remove the mid migration that south failed on, as I hoped it would. What are my options now in order to deal with this

1. Do I even have to do anything, or can I keep working on my app or is this mid migration something to address? I ask because the new MYSQL DB seems to have the new field I added, which was why I wanted to migrate in the first place. So you can see my confusion...my migration broke, but now with MYSQL, the fields are fine, but Django still thinks im in the middle of a migration. Why is this and what is the recommendations?

thanks

Comment: When I run syncdb -all, that removed accounts from "not synced" and added to "synced". But if I run syncdb accounts is reported as "not synced" again. Just and FYI, I have no idea what this means and still need advice on this. Django newbie.

Comment: Which is your django version ?

Comment: Thanks @Liarez, but I have moved on from Django as it was more than I needed. Have not used it in over 6 months. My apps are real small. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fought many many many (many) times with Databases & Migrations & South... I hope this information helps you to fix your issues and save you some hours of hard work

## Migrating accounts app

- I have a question here, is `accounts` the name of your app ? Or is it an external app ?

The `accounts` app seems to be managed by South, that means that It won't be synced with the command `python manage.py syncdb`, you will need to migrate it by yourself with:

```
# This command generates the migrations file
python manage.py shchemamigration accounts --initial
# This command use the migrations file and apply the changes to the DB
python manage.py migrate accounts


# --initial is used only in the INITIAL migration
# If you modify the models on the accounts app and want to migrate again
# You will need to
python manage.py shchemamigration accounts --auto
python manage.py migrate accounts
```

## Keep an eye on your migrations

If you check the folder `migrations` following the standard structure it is `yourapp/yourapp/migrations`

- If you *delete* your **database**, remember to **delete** your **migrations** files, is better to start over unless you need to save the Database changes
- Make sure that your Database and your migrations are synchronized, if they are synchronized add some changes to the database will be easy
- Some times, although you're **using south**, when you do `python manage.py syncdb` **your app** will be **synced**, I will explain which problems can come from here:

  1. Your app models are created in the database with the command `python manage.py syncdb`
  2. After 1. you  do `python manage.py schemamigration --initial` and it will create the initial migrations
  3. Now, if you try to do `python manage.py migrate yourapp` **it will fail** because the tables has already been created, so **you need to fake the initial migration** with:

     ```
     python manage.py migrate yourapp --fake
     ```

     and from here you could use south without problems

## How to "restart" the database

**This process will empty the database and delete all the migrations, take care if you have some data you want to save**

Sometimes you will mess with the migrations, and depending on the issue, it can be faster to drop the database and start the migrations again:

```
python manage.py dbshell

# Next 3 lines inside the MySQL console
>> drop database yourappdatabase
>> create database yourappdatabase
>> quit

# Delete all the migrations within the migrations folder
rm yourapp/yourapp/migrations/00*

python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py schemamigration yourapp --initial
python manage.py migrate yourapp
```

## How to save informations from the database

Some times when you're starting a new app you will delete/create the database many times, and to avoid typing again and again data on the models, it could be useful to create migrations from some models with:

```
python manage.py dumpdata yourapp.ModelName > file.json
```

To reload this data again you just need to:

```
python manage.py loaddata file.json
```